# how to combine seperated date to datetime in a dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a dataframe and there is three column for date (day, month, year).
I want to combine these three columns to one date column for further use.
I want to use date column for referring and plotting in matplotlib axis. 
[image]

I tried this `(lambda x:'%s %2s %2s' % (x['year'],x['month'], x['day']),axis=1)` for create a new column and use that but it creates a string so i use `matplotlib.dates.datestr2num()` but however it is not working either.

**question summary**

how to combine those three columns to use as datetime in both dataframe and 
matplotlib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with subset `day`, `month`, `year`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.DataFrame({'day':[1,2,3,4,3,4,5],
                   'month':[4,5,7,4,5,6,8],
                   'year':[2013,2013,2103,2013,2013,2103,2013],
                   'A':[1,3,5,5,6,7,9],
                   'B':[4,5,6,5,4,3,4]})

#print (df)

#convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['day','month','year']])
print (df)
   A  B  day  month  year       date
0  1  4    1      4  2013 2013-04-01
1  3  5    2      5  2013 2013-05-02
2  5  6    3      7  2103 2103-07-03
3  5  5    4      4  2013 2013-04-04
4  6  4    3      5  2013 2013-05-03
5  7  3    4      6  2103 2103-06-04
6  9  4    5      8  2013 2013-08-05
```

```
#remove columns
df.drop(['day','month','year'], axis=1, inplace=True)
#set index from date dolumn - datetimeindex
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
print (df)
            A  B
date            
2013-04-01  1  4
2013-05-02  3  5
2103-07-03  5  6
2013-04-04  5  5
2013-05-03  6  4
2103-06-04  7  3
2013-08-05  9  4

#plot and set format of axis x:
ax = df.plot()
ticklabels = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
plt.show()
```

Comment: i did but i got: ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: day is out of range for month

Comment: what is your pandas version? `pd.show_versions()` ?

Comment: pandas version --- 
pandas: 0.19.1

Comment: Try test problematic row by `print (df[pd.to_datetime(df[['day','month','year']], errors='coerce').isnull()])`

Comment: it works if add `error='coerce'` `to_datetime` convert all problematic values to `NaN`, so if check where are `NaN` get all rows, where is impossible convert to datetime.

Comment: There is one problematic row in the dataframe. i remove
 it and it is now working. Thanks

Comment: Super, I add solution for formatting dates in `matplotlib`, but there can be more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using string:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('<date string>', '%d%m%Y').date()
```